# Issue with Pandas Loop: Column Repeats Every 10 Rows in Excel Data Extraction

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I'm using Python and Pandas in a `'for i in range(10)'` loop to extract data from an Excel file. However, I'm encountering an issue where the desired column keeps repeating every 10 rows instead of continuing seamlessly.

Here's the column that I am looping through:

[image]

Ideally, within the loop, I'd like the output to look like this.

[image]

But this is what I am getting as an output. 17.25 which is the first value in the loop keeps repeating after 10 rows. Could you please let me know why this is happening and how I can make it continue with the values in the next rows instead of repeating them?

[image]

Comment: Please share your code in OP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Code, data and error tracebacks are required to be posted as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your post accordingly. Dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`. Probably: start with what you've imported from Excel. In fact: Solve the problem within Python. Does not look Excel related

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to advise without seeing your code so I will try my best.

It seems that your loop is programmed in such a way that it is populating the value from a single cell 10 times. In your case, it is outputting the cell with the value 17.25, 10 times. You might want to relook at what the loop is outputting.